# Asp.net MVC url rewrite action and id with name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

Asp.net Mvc Url MapRoute does not recognize the rout without Action:

> Error: **A public action method was not found on controller**

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "WorldWithoutAction",
             "World/{id}/{name}",
             new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });
```

Although trying this to catch World/Details but same error occurred:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "World",
            url: "World",
            defaults: new { controller = "World", action = "Details" }
        );
```

What shoud I do to catch http://domain.com/world/1/australia to http://domain.com/world/details/1?
Seems that it just accept action instead of {id} in url.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
             "Default",
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
             "Default2",
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
             new { controller = "Agency", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
             "Default3",
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
             new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
             new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
             "WorldWithoutAction",
             "World/{id}/{name}",
             new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "Details" },
             new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "World",
            url: "World",
            defaults: new { controller = "World", action = "Details" }
        );

    }
```

Comment: In the first case, you need to add a default value for action that matches the name of the controller action method. In the second, do you have a controller named `WorldController` with a method named `Details`?

Comment: Yes I have WorldController with Details(int id)

Comment: Have you tried in the first case adding a default action like `new { id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional, action = "Details" },`?

Comment: A public action method '1' was not found on controller. after adding in thr first case.

Comment: is the default route defined before those routes? because it looks like the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route is being used?

Comment: I added my RegisterRoutes method, please take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62322/discussion-between-azarsa-and-daniel-j-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder your routes so the most specific routes are defined first. You also need to provide default values for:

- `controller` and `action` when they don't appear in the route
- Any other parameter required by the action method. (For example in a method `Details(int id)` id is required and so in your route you need to either add a segment `{id}` or a default value)

Also, your default routes won't work well with each other, you may want to rethink/simplify them. For example, you could hardcode the controller to "Agency" in default2 and combine default and default3 together.

With all these changes, your routes definition would look something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "World",
        url: "World",
        defaults: new { controller = "World", action = "Details", id = 0 }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "WorldWithoutAction",
        "World/{id}/{name}",
        new { controller = "World", action = "Details", id = 0, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultAgency",
        "Agency/{action}/{id}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Agency", action = "Show", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

As discussed in the chat, it might not make sense to declare the id as optional for controller actions that require a valid id to retrieve data. You might need to find another solution for having SEO friendly urls.

Comment: In fact "URLs are Matched Against Routes in Order – The First Match Wins"